# Installing A Dual Boot with 16.04 and 17.XX On Separate HDD's In One Notebook

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, hard-drive, 17.10

I would like to have two versions of Ubuntu installed on my laptop onto two separate HDD's. I can install Linux successfully but when it comes to messing around with the partitions I get lost and the main problem is I don't know anything about boot up management. If someone could write a step by step guide how to do that it would be great. Its because I don't possess any skills required to do such a thing and need your help. I tried installing them at the same time on the separate HDD's but only the latest installation launches. I want full access to both distributions of Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.xx on a dual boot from one HDD, not just one. I have failed with this task for a couple of days now so somebody who has a clue what they're doing please help me.

Cheers

Comment: UEFI or BIOS. But either way install in same boot mode. Easiest is to disconnect current Ubuntu drive and install in other drive. You may just need to turn off drive in UEFI/BIOS, or physically disconnect. best to partition in advance, but not required. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu For my test installs I just create a 25GB ext4 partition for / (root). I do have a large shared data partition which I mount in all installs, so / & /home which is inside / partition does not get too large.

Comment: Does your notebook have two physical hard drives or one physical hard drive with multiple partitions? Have you successfully installed Ubuntu once? How did you install it? Please add more details to the original question above.

Comment: I have 2 physical Hard drives. I did installed Ubuntu successfully a couple of times (not the way I wanted to but it was working). Any details I need provide I happy to provide I really want to get this done as soon as I can.

Comment: What do you mean by "not the way I want?"

Comment: @oldfred Consider turning your comment to an answer.

Comment: Need to know if UEFI or BIOS, as BIOS is straight forward, even if both drives connected. If first drive disconnected, also straight forward. But if you leave both drives connected & UEFI (which I do), makes it more complicated as Ubuntu's grub will only install to ESP - efi system partition on first drive, sda or NVMe.

Comment: Install OS1 to first drive, remove hard drive and install OS2 to second hard drive. replace first hard drive and boot. Run sudo update-grub. Both OS should be available in grub menu next boot. (assumes BIOS boot). This can also be done in "Something else" without removing hard drives. You can also install several versions to a single hard drive if desired.